# hover color and active of a sub list

Tags: html, css

I have a sub list within a list and everything works fine except for the active/hover color of the child item. 
When you expand a menu/list item the sub items have the non-hover color but the rest of the item has the active item color.  Is there a way to sync them so they don't look out of place and give them their own hover color? In order words when the parent item get the active the subitems get the same active color until the subitem get a different active color.  I know someone is going to say what the hell are you talking about.  It's easier to see at the Fiddler Link: 
https://jsfiddle.net/morgenweck/46oq2x18/13/

```
            .lmainlist ul li a {
            color: #2f6176;
           text-decoration: none;
               }

         .leftmain ul li:hover {
         background-color: #b5d0d8;
              }

           .lmainlist ul li:active {
          background-color: #878b8c;
            }

          ul.collapseable{
            display: none;
             }
```

I've looked at [Retain color of main-menu when hovering sub-menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043982/retain-color-of-main-menu-when-hovering-sub-menu) But I think it is much more than I need and confuses me.

Comment: Can I ask for clarification on what you are looking for? What color would you like the sub-items to be when the item is opened? What color would you like them to be on hover?

Comment: @user1314159 Are you talking about having different background-color within your child's items and parent items? If yes, are you looking for something like this one style rule `.leftmain ul li li:hover`?

Comment: Sorry- I know it's confusing.  and as rewrite this a half dozen time I think it comes down that I want to make the .lmainlist ul li li a color the same as the active color or the ul li.  I just don't want the lighter gray bars

Answer (score 0):

You have to `toggleClass` in the parent element and add the active state in CSS.

JavaScript:

```
$(".lmainlist > li > a").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");

  if($(this).parent().hasClass("active")){
    $(this).next(".collapseable").slideDown();
  }
  else{
    $(this).next(".collapseable").slideUp();
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
ul.lmainlist li.active {
   background-color: #b5d0d8;
 }
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/upcx2r07/

Comment: Expand "Dashboard" hover over dashboard and all of the sub items are in lighter backgrounds.  I'm looking for it to be the same color as the hover color of the Dashboard

Comment: I got rid of the hover color and it totally looks better.  Thanks all

Comment: Anyway if you desire to overwrite the hover color of the sub items when a parent item is in the ':hover' status then you can try this `.leftmain ul li:hover li {
    background-color: #b5d0d8;}` In this way all the elements 'li' after the first is in the status ':hover' become the same color of your parent 'li' element.